# Баг иконок на Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

Установил убунту на виртуалбокс. Все работало отлично, но потом накатил обновление и иконки изменились на красные прямоугольники с зачеркнутым кругом внутри. Информации по багу не нашел. Прикладываю скрин.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В верхнем правом углу и левый нижний.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Возможно что-то прервало обновление. Это поможет.

```
sudo apt install gnome-icon-theme-symbolic
```

Чтоб установить эти иконки. Если первые 2 команды не помогли. Потом alt+f2, r, энтер

Comment: Спасибо большое.